# How to make an page only accessible when logged in PHP

Tags: php

Currently I'm working on a little project for a dummy login/register page and now I want to add a page that is only accessible when you're logged in.
So the question is how do I make a session or cookie and retrieve them?
And how do I block not logged in users.

I'm currently using these codes for the login.php and member_area.php:
Login.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();





    if(isSet($_POST['login'])) {
        include('db.php');

        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = sha1($_POST['password'] );

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tab WHERE username='".addSlashes($username)."' AND password='".addSlashes($password)."'");
        $res = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if ($res == 1) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
            $_SESSION['userobj'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

            header('Location: http://localhost/member_area.php');
            exit;
        } else {
            echo 'Data does not match <br /> RE-Enter Username and Password';
        }
    } else {

?>
    <html>
    <head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"></head>
        <body>
                <div id="div1">

                <a href="index.php" id="home">Home</a>
                <a href="Login.php" id="login2">Login</a>
                <a href="register.php" id="register">Register</a> 


        </div>
            <table width="200" border="0" cellspacing="1" align="center">
                <form id="form1" method="post" action="login.php">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><h2>Members login</h2></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username: </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password: </td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password"/> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="login" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </form>
            </table>
            </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    }


?>
```

Member_area.php:

```
<?php

?>
<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"></head>
    <body>
            <div id="div1">

                <a href="index.php" id="home">Home</a>
                <a href="Login.php" id="login2">Login</a>
                <a href="register.php" id="register">Register</a> 


        </div>
        <form action="/Log_out.php" method="get">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log Out." action="http://localhost/Log_out.php" id="Logout">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php

?>
```

Please note that I'm completely new to PHP so some directions where to put the code with if possible a little explanation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add this at the top of Member_area.php:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   header("Location:Login.php");
}
```

It checks whether the session is set or not, if not it will redirect the user to login page.

Comment: Well it is sort of working but even if I login with the login page it will redirect me back to the page. is it possible that i need to start a session in the login page? or is it possible that the session gets destroyed some how?

EDIT: Session wasn't starting fixed it.

Comment: I edited the code try now, added `session_start();` at the top

Comment: Upvoted this, wasn't worth the -1 just because you didn't include the session_start().

Comment: @StefanKonno : Your -1 made me to look in to the answer and correct it, Thanks for that :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense : Can you please explain that ?!

Comment: @YourCommonSense Actually if you try it out whitout logging in it won't get you there it will redirect you back to the login page or in my case a page where you will get a pop up saying you have to login first.

Comment: @user2099594 : Edited as per your suggestion, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    die("Please login");
}

?>
<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"></head>
    <body>
            <div id="div1">

                <a href="index.php" id="home">Home</a>
                <a href="Login.php" id="login2">Login</a>
                <a href="register.php" id="register">Register</a> 


        </div>
        <form action="/Log_out.php" method="get">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log Out." action="http://localhost/Log_out.php" id="Logout">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php

?>
```

That should be it :)

Comment: `session_start();` is not added :)

Comment: Prasanth was right you forgot to start the session but thanks :D!

Comment: Oh yes, I'm so sorry. I totally forgot about that!